# Fetching proper route path

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes

So I am trying to fetch and display players that belong to team. I have a dropdown button which has a selection of said teams and on click, it should render the chosen team's players. The problem I have is that on click, it renders all of the players in my seed data, irrelevant of the team it belongs to. I am not sure what I am missing but here is the code I have. In Postman when I put "http://localhost:3000/api/teams/1/players" it is returning all of the players instead of just the one that belongs to team with id 1.

Edit: I fixed the issue with filtering data as now the url "http://localhost:3000/api/teams/1/players" in Postman works correctly. However I am getting 'TypeError: this.props.players.cards.map is not a function' from the DataContainer when it tries to render the players after clicking the team on the dropdown button. All I did was change the index in my controller. Also the terminal says "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Team with 'id'=Chaos):"

Here is my players controller:

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_params, only: [:show]

def index
  @players = Team.find(params[:team_id]).players
  render json: @players, status: 200
end

def show
  render json: @player, status: 200
end

private

def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:name, :player_type, :cost, 
  :movement_allowance, :strength, :agility, :armour_value, :skills, 
  :team_id)
end

def set_params
  @player = Player.find(params[:id])
end
```

My filter file which contains the dropdown button (edited):

```
class PlayerFilter extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { data: [] };
}

async fetchButtonTeams() {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/teams`);
  const json = await response.json();
  this.setState({ data: json });
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchButtonTeams()
}

handleTeamSelection = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { target: { title }} = e;
    this.props.setTeam(title);
    this.props.fetchPlayers(title);
};

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <DropdownButton id="dropdown-player-button" title={this.props.team}>
                      {this.state.data.map(team => (
                        <div key={team}>
                            <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleTeamSelection} title={team.name}>{team.name}</Dropdown.Item>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </DropdownButton>
            </Row>
        </Container>
      )
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        team: state.players.team
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchPlayers: params => dispatch(fetchPlayers(params)),
        fetchTeams: params => dispatch(fetchTeams(params)),
        setTeam: team => dispatch({ type: "SET_TEAM", team })

    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PlayerFilter)
```

My player fetch being called in the filter (edited)

```
export const fetchPlayers = teamId => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_PLAYERS' });
    fetch(`/api/teams/${teamId}/players`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(responseJSON => { dispatch({ type: 'ADD_PLAYERS', cards: responseJSON})
        })
}
```

My DataContainer:

```
class DataContainer extends Component {

displayCards = () => {
    switch(this.props.path) {
        case "teams":
            return (this.props.teams.cards.map(card => (
              <NavLink style={{ color: "black" }} to={`/teams/${card.id}`} key={card.id}><TeamCard info={card} /></NavLink>
          )));

        case "players":
            return (this.props.players.cards.map(card => (
              <NavLink style={{ color: "black" }} to={`/players/${card.id}`} key={card.id}><PlayerCard info={card} /></NavLink>
          )));

        default:
            return (<div>Empty</div>)
    }
};

render() {
    return (
        <CardColumns>
            {this.displayCards()}
        </CardColumns>
      )
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        teams: state.teams,
        players: state.players
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DataContainer)
```

My app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import NavButtonsContainer  from './containers/NavButtonsContainer';
import DataContainer from "./containers/DataContainer";

import PlayerDisplay from "./components/PlayerDisplay";
import PlayerFilter from "./components/PlayerFilter";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row"
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col"

const App = props => {
  return (
    <Container>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/teams/:id">
                    <TeamDisplay info={props.info} />
                </Route>

                <Route path="/players/:id">
                    <PlayerDisplay info={props.info} />
                </Route>

                <Route path="/teams">
                    <Row>
                        <Col><TeamFilter path="teams" /></Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <NavButtonsContainer />
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <DataContainer path="teams" />
                    </Row>
                </Route>

                <Route path="/players">
                    <Row>
                        <Col><PlayerFilter path="players" /></Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <NavButtonsContainer />
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <DataContainer path="players" />
                    </Row>
                </Route>

                <Route path="/">
                       <NavButtonsContainer />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Container>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        info: state.piece
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Your `fetchPlayers` is fetching from the literal string "/api/teams/:id/players" which your server likely can't process. You likely meant to, from your drop down menu, push/navigate to your '/api/teams/:id/players' route (i.e. push(`/api/teams/${team.id}/players`)) where then upon mounting pulls the route's match params and makes a fetch request to get the players of a specific team. If you can share what your response data shape is, and the component(s) of your app and router, we'll have a better lay of the land and we can probably point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Or you're not actually doing *any* routing and you just need to build the fetch URL correctly from the passed `params` in `fetchPlayers`. Is the team title the same as the `id`? I think your `fetchPlayers` will need to be reworked a bit. It's odd that it *slightly* resembles an async action. You're using a class-based component so it's clear you're not using a `useReducer` or any of the redux hooks, but it isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Drew Reese I added the app. The title is the team name since that is what I want the dropdown button to show. The player reducer also has a set team case which is responsible for actually showing which team is selected. Could you show how the push should be written in the dropdown button syntax wise?

Comment: @DrewReese also how do I show response data?

Comment: Sure, but I need more details. What does the `id` value correlate to and where does it come from in the routes that don't have it in the URL? I think my initial assumption that you're trying to navigate from "/players" where you're rendering `PlayerFilter` to another route was incorrect. Are you simply trying to fetch all the players from a specific team by `id` and display them on the current route?

Comment: Also, you're fundamentally using the `Route` component incorrectly by simply wrapping elements; you should use the `render` prop so you can pass the `match` prop and unpack the `id` route parameter from the url.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I am trying to fetch all the players from specific team by id and display on the current route. So when I am on the players route, I click the dropdown button and choose my team and want to display the team's players. And the id value is correlating to the teams and players and coming from their controllers where id param is set if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. `handleTeamSelection` isn't passing an `id/title` as a parameter to the `fetchPlayers` action creator, and you need to build the interpolated url string as `/api/teams/${id}/players` where `id` is the value passed via the callback from the dropdown. Is it a correct assumption that you have a reducer to handle the `type: 'ADD_PLAYERS'` response that is then fed to the `<DataContainer path="players" />` from your redux store? Is it possible to share a codesandbox of your app?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I do have ADD_PLAYERS case in my players reducer. For some reason though, I can't import my app to codesandbox, getting 'Request failed with status code 422'. Is it ok if I give you my github?Maybe it might work for you. https://github.com/Gorgutzz/bb2-teams-app

Answer (score 1):

It was a little confusing calling your action creator parameter `params`, but I believe you need to access an (some) `id` property from it to correctly construct your request URL path. Giving parameters better, more meaningful names goes a long way in code readability.

```
export const fetchPlayers = teamId => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_PLAYERS' });
    fetch(`/api/teams/${teamId}/players`) // interpolate id into path string
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(responseJSON => { dispatch({ type: 'ADD_PLAYERS', cards: responseJSON});
  });
}
```

The next part is to call this action with the correct parameter from the handler.

```
// Playerfilter
handleTeamSelection = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { target: { title }} = e;
  this.props.setTeam(title);
  this.props.fetchPlayers(title); // This is what I'm not sure about, but I'll get to that later
};
```

I couldn't immediately tell from the react-bootstrap docs on `Dropdown.Item` if it passes extra props to children (i.e. your `title` prop) or what is passed with the `onClick` and `onSelect` handlers (other than an event), or if perhaps it is more like an html select element where your handler needs to be bound to the `Dropdown`'s `onSelect` prop instead of on each item.

I also took a peek at your db directory to try and glean your `teams` schema to figure out what the `id` field is. I noticed there is nothing relating your `teams` table to your `players` table, i.e. the `players` table has a field `team_id` that looks like it should be a foreign key *into* `teams`, so you can do a join. Maybe this is by design and you don't need to do multi-table queries.

> In Postman when I put "http://localhost:3000/api/teams/1/players" it is
>   returning all of the players instead of just the one that belongs to
>   team with id 1

If this is your local server not returning filtered data, then this is indicative of an issue with your server code not querying your DB correctly and returning bad results.

I think you should first sort out your DB issue(s) and ensure it is returning correct responses, then tackle your client code to ensure it is making requests correctly.

Comment: I fixed my db issue and now I can see Postman returns the correct players when I put ""http://localhost:3000/api/teams/1/players". However I am getting 'TypeError: this.props.players.cards.map is not a function' from the DataContainer when it tries to render the players after clicking the team on the dropdown button. I changed the index of the players controller to "@players = Team.find(params[:team_id]).players". from "@players = Player.all" and this is causing the issue. Not sure why though.

Comment: Terminal says "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Team with 'id'=Chaos):" I am not sure how I should setup my players controller for it to work.

Comment: Can you instead update your question with these further issues versus conversing here in an answer? What is the shape of `responseJSON` in your action creators? If it isn't an array (or any object without a map function) then `this.props.players.cards` will fail as it has.

Comment: I updated question. Also I edited the fetchPlayers in dataActions and Player Fitler with the code you showed. ActiveRecord should be finding team with 'id'=1 instead of looking for 'id'=Chaos since its not looking based on name, right?